# Elixir Ecto - compile items into single items by their share field value

Tags: elixir, ecto

if I have:

```
[
%{group: "123", name: "John"},
%{group: "123", name: "Jane"},
%{group: "123", name: "James"},
]
```

how can i transform it into:

```
%{
group: "123", 
members: [%{name: "John"}, %{name: "Jane"}, %{name: "James"}]
}
```

?

I try:

```
from m in Module.Member,
group_by: m.group, 
... #with a few different queries...
```

but just learned that that is not how group_by works

Comment: You may want to take a look at `Enum.group_by/3` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#group_by/3

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of generality you want, this may be sufficient:

```
data = [
  %{group: "123", name: "John"},
  %{group: "123", name: "Jane"},
  %{group: "123", name: "James"},
]

members = Enum.map(data, fn p -> %{name: p.name} end)
result = %{group: Enum.at(data, 0).group, members: members}
```

This does not handle cases like different group numbers in the data.